# Typescript - Returning a promise from a generic method

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

I have an issue where I am trying to return a promise from one of my methods, however, it complains that the type 'is not assignable'. See example below:

```
interface Test {
    prop1: string
}

interface Interface {
    oneMethod<T>(): Promise<T>;
}

class implementation implements Interface {
    oneMethod<Test>(): Promise<Test> {
        return Promise.resolve({
            prop1: 'test'
        });
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
error TS2322: Type 'Promise<{ prop1: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Test>'.
  Type '{ prop1: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Test'.
```

I have tried adding 'as Test' to the return object but that then returns the issue 'cannot be converted to Type Test'

Annoyingly, this works fine:

```
class anotherImp {

    oneMethod(): Promise<Test> {
        return Promise.resolve({
            prop1: 'test'
        });
    }
}
```

but this is not implementing my generic interface. If I remove the T from the oneMethod signature in the interface, then I get an error about the Promise not knowing T (Cannot find name 'T'). Removing from both gives me the error that Promise must implement a type (Generic type 'Promise' requires 1 type argument(s).)

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Thanks
Iain

Comment: `oneMethod<Test>(): Promise<Test>`is equivalent to `oneMethod<T>(): Promise<T>`: it's just that you chose to name the generic parameter Test instead of T. And `{ prop1: 'test' }` is not of type T. You probably want Interface to be a generic interface, and implementation to implement interface<Test>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
interface Test {
    prop1: string
}

interface Interface<T> {
    oneMethod(): Promise<T>;
}

class implementation implements Interface<Test> {
    oneMethod(): Promise<Test> {
        return Promise.resolve({
            prop1: 'test'
        });
    }
}
```

When you define a method/function as `method<Type>(): Type` you're not returning the existent type `Type` (if any). You're telling TypeScript that that method is generic and will return whatever type you indicate through the type parameter.

Normally, you won't have a generic method in a non-generic interface. It is better to define the interface as generic, so the method depends on the type of the interface. Otherwise, you could just define a type as generic function forget about the interface.

Comment: Thanks Oscar &JB Nizet. I changed to a generic interface and it works fine now.